# Quelle est la différence entre « soutenir » et « étayer » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

*Soutenir* et *étayer* : certains dictionnaires les présentent comme des synonymes. Y a-t-il une différence ?

Comment: L'un est plus précis que l'autre ? Est-ce que c'est dans un contexte particulier, au sens figuré ? Ou très matériel ?

Comment: Dans le contexte de présentant un argument. Je pense que les deux peuvent être utilisés au sens figuré ?

Comment: "soutenir une position" vs "étayer ses propos" donc.

Comment: Peut-être ; je ne sais pas :) Cela est ma question.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a beaucoup de différences entre les deux.

- *Étayer* s'emploie surtout à l'infinitif, *soutenir* se conjugue couramment.
- Au sens propre, étayer implique l'utilisation d'étais ou de quelque chose qui y ressemble alors que n'importe quoi peut soutenir n'importe quoi. On n'étaye le plus souvent qu'une chose alors qu'on peut soutenir une animal ou une personne. De plus, étayer correspond plus une solution intentionnelle et provisoire, alors qu'un soutien peut aussi être accidentel et pérenne.
- Au sens figuré du contexte de la question (arguments), les deux verbes ne s'emploient pas vraiment de façon interchangeable. Soutenir introduit une opinion alors qu'étayer consiste à apporter les arguments qui expliquent pourquoi on la soutient.

> Il soutient que la terre est plate.

> Il <s>étaye</s> que la terre est plate.

> Il étaye ses arguments.

> Il soutient ses arguments. (?)

Answer (score 0):

A ma connaissance, la nuance dans l'usage est la suivante :

- on **soutient** une autre personne,
- on **soutient** une thèse, ou la position de quelqu'un d'autre sur un sujet.
- on **soutient que** quelque chose est ainsi ou autrement (= affirmer que).

En revanche, on **étaie** :

- un propos
- une affirmation
- un argument

d'autre part, il me semble que l'on n'**étaie** généralement pas les propos d'une autre personne.

---

La nuance de sens est la suivante :

- dans le cas de **soutenir**, on porte/supporte un édifice (qui sinon s'écroule)
- dans le cas d'**étayer**, on renforce/solidifie une construction/un ouvrage qui tient déjà debout.

Je pense que ça se retrouve au sens métaphorique : les choses que l'on étaie sont plus élaborées que celles que l'on soutient.

Comment: En construction, étayer, c'est placer des étais. Ces étais viennent ensuite soutenir un édifice qui sinon s'écroule..

Comment: @LaurentS. Je pensais à l'exemple classique d'une galerie de mine : on l'étaie au fur et à mesure qu'on la creuse, mais ça tient "tout seul" au départ.